# Can anyone help explain why the time complexity for this is O(n)

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, big-o-notation

So ive already tried lookig at it but i just get O(nlogn) which is not correct
there were some clues like using a geometric series where 1/2+2/4+3/8+i/2^i<2 but idk how to implement that what should i do.

```
 for i = 1, . . . , n do
    
        j = n
    
        while j > i do
    
           j = j/2
            Do smth
    
return sum
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `do smth` instruction runs in constant time, and ignoring the `return sum` instruction since `sum` is undefined, the overall time complexity is asymptotically upper bounded by the number of iterations of the inner loop. This is monotonically increasing with $n$, so let $2^k$ be the first power of two that greater than $n$ (notice that $2^k \le 2n$).

For a fixed value of $i$, the inner loop does at most $ 1+ \log_2 \frac{n}{i} \le  1+ \log_2 \frac{2^k}{i}$  iterations. Summing over all values of $i$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{2^k-1} \left( 1+ \log_2 \frac{2^k}{i} \right)
&\le 2^k + \sum_{i=1}^{2^k-1}\log_2 \frac{2^k}{i}
\le 2^k + \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \sum_{i=2^j}^{2^{j+1}-1} \log_2 \frac{2^k}{i}  \\
&\le 2^k +\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} 2^j \cdot \log_2 2^{k-j} 
=  2^k + 2^k \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{k-j}{2^{k-j}} \\ 
&=  2^k + 2^k \sum_{j=1}^{k} \frac{j}{2^j} 
<2^k + 2 \cdot 2^k = 3 \cdot 2^k \le 6n,
\end{align*}
$$
where we used the fact that $\sum_{j=1}^{k} \frac{j}{2^j}$ is an [Arithmetico-geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence) of ratio $\frac{1}{2}$ (which was the hint you got).

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop is repeated $k$ times, as long as it holds: $\frac{n}{2^k}>i$, i.e.:

$$\frac{n}{2^k}>i \iff \frac{n}{i}>2^k \iff \log_2 \left(\frac{n}{i}\right) > k \ .$$

So we have $\log_2 \frac{n}{i}$ iterations of each outside loop, which means that the total number of iterations is:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n\log_2 \left( \frac{n}{i} \right) &= \log_2 \left( \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{n}{i} \right) = \log_2 \frac{n^n}{n!} = n\log_2 n - \log_2 (n!) = n\log_2 n - \frac{\log (n!)}{\ln 2}\\
\small{\text{Stirling formula}}\longrightarrow &= n \log_2 n - \left(n \frac{\ln n}{\ln 2} - \frac{n}{\ln 2} +O(\log n)\right) \\
&= n \log_2 n - \left(n \log_2 n -\frac{n}{\ln 2} +O(\log n)\right) \\
&=\frac{n}{\ln 2} + O(\log n)= O(n)
\end{align*}

Comment: How do you get $\log_2(n!) \sim n \ln n - n + O(\log n)$? Notice that different bases of the logarithms.

Comment: @Steven of course I've misread the basis, thanks! Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Steven's answer's the best but that's too smart and tricky, I'll just use induction if I see this in exam :)

proposition: Since $\sum_{i=1}^n\lg (n/i) = \sum_{i=1}^n(\lg n - \lg i )=n\lg n - \sum_{i=1}^n \lg i = n\lg n - \lg (n!)$, we propose

$$
n\lg n - \lg (n!) \le cn
$$
for $n\ge n_0 > 0,c>0$

induction: assume proposition holds for $k\ge n_0$, then because $\lg ((k+1)!)=\lg ((k+1)k!)=\lg (k+1)+\lg (k!)$ and

$$
(k+1)\lg (k+1)=k\lg (k+1) + \lg (k+1)\\
< k( \lg k  + 1/k) + \lg (k+1)\\
= k\lg k+ 1 + \lg (k+1)
$$

where we used $\lg (k+1) - \lg k < 1/k$ [1], we have

$$
(k+1)\lg (k+1)  - \lg ((k+1)!) < k\lg k - \lg (k!) + 1 \\
\le ck + 1 \\
\le ck + c = c(k+1)
$$

for $c\ge 1$.

base case:

consider $n_0=2$, we have $2\lg 2 - \lg (2!)=2-1=1\le c2$, for $c\ge 1/2$.

Finally, since proposition is the definition of the Big-$O$ notation, we've proven the run time $\sum_{i=1}^n\lg (n/i)=O(n)$.

[1][nice trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2859331/897319)